# Copy multiple columns from a table to another table with extra columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to copy records from one table to another table with extra columns.
The table columns looks like this

```
Table1: A,B,C,...,X
Table2: A,B,C,...,X,Y,Z
```

I know that i can do it in the following way

```
Insert into table2
  Select
  A,
  B,
  C, 
  ...
  X,
  '1',
  '1'
  from table1
```

But it is a very inefficient way if the table contains lots of columns. I need to do the similar procedure for several tables. Is there a better way to do it?
I tried the following but it doesn't work

```
insert into table2 select * , '1', '1'  from table1;
```

Comment: Please tag your DBMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you tried should work, just add alias.

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT t1.*,
       '1',
       '1'
  FROM table1 t1;
```

Comment: If you use `SELECT * FROM table1`, it translates to `col1, col2, ...., coln`. SQL syntax can't expect anything but `FROM` keyword in this case. But when you use an alias, the syntax allows you to add more columns to the list, maybe because it might think can encounter joins(i think so). Even if you don't use alias, you can use the full table name also, like `SELECT table1.*, '1' FROM table1`

Answer (score 0):

Insert into table2 ( A,  B,   C, ... , X, Y , Z)   SELECT ( A,  B,   C, ... , X, '1' , '1') from table1 ;

In this case Y & Z are Strings (characters).